# Compare Variables After Function Runs - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm new to Xcode and swift and am creating an alarm clock app. I can't figure out how to start checking if the time set by the user for the alarm to go off (alarmTime) is equal to the current time.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var alarmBeep = AVAudioPlayer()
    var alarmTime = String?()

    @IBOutlet weak var AlarmSetLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TimeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func SetAlarm(sender: UIButton) {
        setAlarmTime()  
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var AlarmButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func AlarmButton(sender: UIButton) {
        alarmOff()  
    }

    func twoDigits(number : Int) -> String {

        var outNum = String(number)
        if outNum.characters.count == 1 {
            outNum = "0" + outNum
        }
        return outNum
    }

    func setAlarmTime() {
        self.alarmTime = "17:38"
        AlarmSetLabel.text = "Alarm Set for " + self.alarmTime!

        //Start checking at this point
    }


    func compareTimes(time: String) {

        if self.alarmTime == time {
            alarmBeep.play()
            AlarmButton.setTitle("Turn Off Alarm", forState: .Normal)
        }

    }

    func alarmOff() {
        alarmBeep.stop()
        self.alarmTime = nil
    }



    func currentTime() -> String {
        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components([ .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)

        let hour = twoDigits(components.hour)

        let minutes = twoDigits(components.minute)

        TimeLabel.text = hour + ":" + minutes

        return hour + ":" + minutes

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        currentTime()
        _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target:self, selector: Selector("currentTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


        //_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target:currentTime(), selector: Selector("compareTimes"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


        let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Bleep-sound", ofType: "mp3")

        if let filePath = filePath {
            let filePathURL =  NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

            do {

                try alarmBeep = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathURL)
                alarmBeep.numberOfLoops = -1
                //alarmBeep.play()
            }
            catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }

    }


}
```

I think this would be done by running some code either inside the setAlarm function when the user sets the alarm or in viewDidLoad(). The commented out line was my attempt but it doesn't work.

How would I check if the current and set times are the same?

Comment: Do not begin variable and function names with a capital letter, please. It makes your code illegible.

Comment: @matt Sorry, I don't know about standards in swift yet. Only the IBActions and IBOutlets begin with capital letters if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the math with `NSDate` objects for example set the alarm time

```
let now = NSDate()
self.alarmTime = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateBySettingHour(17, minute: 38, second: 00, ofDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions())
```

and compare the dates continuously in the `currentTime()` method

```
let date = NSDate()
if alarmTime?.compare(date) != .OrderedDescending  {
  print("Alarm")
}
```

`!= .OrderedDescending` means: is `date` equal or later than `alarmTime`

Comment: So I changed the time on my NSTimer to 1 second so that it can precisely detect if alarmTime is equal to date. When they become equal, "Alarm" isn't printed  for some reason.

Comment: `NSDate` can have a finer precision than seconds. That's why I suggested the `.OrderedDescending` syntax.

Comment: If I use order descending, "Alarm" will be output if I set an alarm for the next day. Is there a way to compare just the hours and minutes?

Comment: I apologize, it's the contrary. I updated the answer

Comment: From what I can tell, it does the same thing. What changes did you make to the answer?

Comment: It's **not**  `is alarmTime equal or later than date` -  it's `is date equal or later than alarmTime`

Comment: I figured it out, by using a range, the alarm will only go off within the space of a minute. 
`if alarmTime != nil {
            let upperTime = alarmTime!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60)
            if alarmTime?.compare(date) != .OrderedDescending && upperTime.compare(date) != .OrderedAscending {
                print("Alarm")
                alarmBeep.play()
            }`